# Do the scriptures mandate that the devotee regularly visit a temple?

Tags: worship

Is there any mention in the scriptures to regularly visit temples?

Comment: Devotees will not be required to be specially instructed to go to temples because they themselves would love to do so as often as they can.. daily visits may not be possible for all though.. As regards scriptural instructions then the Vedas, smritis do not talk about temples only the Puranas do.. so they may have the required answer..

Comment: I think you can post this as the answer

Comment: haha no.. i can not because we need to back our answers up with sources from some scriptures.. if i post that comment as an answer, then it will be deleted..so if i find some reference as such i will then post an answer..

Comment: no. temples are a later development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this chapter of Skanda Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/skanda_purana/virtues_of_worshipping_lord_shiva.html):

> Sage Lomesh told the assembled sages--- One who brooms the courtyard of Shiva **temple**" attains to Shiva loka. Those who make offerings of incense to Lord Shiva not only liberate himself from the bondage of this world but also both his 'Kulas'. One who gets constructed a Shiva temple or renovates it, attains incomparable virtue. One who chants the holy mantra 'Om Namah Shivay' daily and **begins his day by visiting Shiva temple in the morning** becomes absolved of all his sins.

So visiting temple is recommended but it's not mandatory. However, most of the Puranas recommend visiting pilgrimage/holy places which includes temples as well.